# Can not debug on simulator or device anymore

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I was able to debug my Xamarin.iOS app on my physical device and simulators just fine until this morning. I think it has something to do with the recent iOS update. When I try to deploy to my physical device (iPad) I get this message now:

> error HE0003: Could not load the framework 'IBFoundation' (path:
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IBFoundation.framework/IBFoundation):
> not found.

And I can't deploy on any simulator anymore, I get this message

> Lower the deployment target to see older simulators or check you Apple
> SDK path

I didn't have these problems yesterday and I've been working on my app for months without this problem. I updated Visual Studio, Xcode, and my Mac, but these problems still persist. Any idea how to fix?

Comment: you need to install the newest XCode with iOS 15 support, and the pre-release versions of Xamarin with iOS 15 support

Comment: I updated Xcode to version 13.0 and switched Visual Studio to the Preview Channel. Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a known issue that you can follow here: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/12778

Also there are few workarounds that work mentioned in the issue.