# Xamarin Forms XAML HotReload is not working on Mac

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, hot-reload

I can not for the life of me get XAML hot reloading working on Visual Studio (Mac).

- Link behavior is set to "Don't Link"
- XAML hot reload is enabled in Visual Studio Settings
- Visual Studio and all Nuget packages are up to date.
- This first started occurring in my app, so to test, I started with the Xamarin sample app and that won't reload either.

Here is the output from the XAMAL Hot reload window:

```
[12:49:40 PM]  XAML Hot Reload is using 'changes only' mode
[12:49:51 PM]  Xaml Changed for 'Views/AboutPage.xaml' in 'hotreloadtest', sending to app...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can not debug on simulator or device anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69272448/can-not-debug-on-simulator-or-device-anymore)

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug for IOS15.

You can learn more about it at this link(https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/XAML-Hot-Reload-does-not-load-with-Xamar/1543082).

It will be fixed soon.